# SwiftUI: pass binding as generic?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observation

I have the following code:

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}


enum ViewRouter: Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    
    static func ==(lhs:ViewRouter, rhs:ViewRouter) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    var id: Int {
        switch self {
        case .carDetails(let car):
            return car.id.hashValue
        case .foodDetails(let food):
            return food.id.hashValue
        }
    }
    
    case carDetails(Car)
    case foodDetails(Food)
    
}

@Observable class TopViewmodel {
    var navPath = NavigationPath()
}

struct TopView: View {
    
    @State var model = TopViewmodel()
    @State var car = Car()
    @State var foodItem = Food()
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $model.navPath) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    model.navPath.append(ViewRouter.foodDetails(foodItem))
                } label: {
                    Text(foodItem.name)
                }
                Button {
                    model.navPath.append(ViewRouter.carDetails(car))
                } label: {
                    Text(car.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: ViewRouter.self) { d in
            switch d {
            case .carDetails(let car):
                ItemView(item: car) // <- Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Car' to expected argument type 'Binding<any ItemViewable>'
            case .foodDetails(let food):
                ItemView(item: food)
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { input in
            car.name = car.name + randomString(length: 6)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
}




// MARK: ITEMS
@Observable class Car:ItemViewable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String = "My Car"
    func changeName() {
        name = name + randomString(length: 5)
    }
}
@Observable class Food:ItemViewable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String = "Apple"
    func changeName() {
        name = name + randomString(length: 5)
    }
}




// MARK: ITEM VIEW
protocol ItemViewable {
    var name:String { get set }
    func changeName()
}
struct ItemView: View {
    
    @Binding var item:ItemViewable
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Item name: \(item.name)")
            Button {
                item.changeName()
            } label: {
                Text("Change name")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**Objective:**
Have `ItemView` work with different models as long as they adopt `ItemViewable` protocol. This allows me to decouple models that adopt `ItemViewable` from the presentation layer and have one view handle any of those models as long as they adopt `ItemViewable`. Not just read, but also edit abilities while on `ItemView`. (thus the need of a `Binding`).

In this example I have two "items", `Car` and `Food`. I want to be able to display and edit (binding) the `name` property of both using only one view. If other parts of the app change the name property on either (timer in here as a dev test...), I want `ItemView` to immediately show the change but I also want to trigger the name change from within `ItemView` when I press the button on it.

**Error:**
at the moment I am not sure how to properly pass in car or food as a binding and I get this error:
`Cannot convert value of type 'Car' to expected argument type 'Binding<any ItemViewable>'`

Comment: `Car` isn't `Binding<Car>`

Comment: You misplaced the `navigationDestination()` call, it should be on the `VStack` not on the `NavigationStack`.

Comment: that fixed the problem. So, it seems like things are working now as suggested by @burnsi. His answer was downvoted. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I was playing around with your code an `Car` and `Food` are reference types you should be using `Bindable` not `Binding`. `Binding` is for value types but it seems that `Bindable` doesn't work with generics right now.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Just FYI you can get Bindable to work by giving ItemViewable everything needed. I guess since the macro look at the item at a very low level it needs everything upfront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `ItemView` to be generic e.g.:

```
struct ItemView<T: ItemViewable>: View {
    
    @Binding var item: T
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Item name: \(item.name)")
            Button {
                item.changeName()
            } label: {
                Text("Change name")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then your navigation becomes:

```
.navigationDestination(for: ViewRouter.self) { d in
    switch d {
    case .carDetails(_):
        ItemView(item: $car) 
    case .foodDetails(_):
        ItemView(item: $foodItem)
    }
}
```

Edit:

In response to the comment. If you want to use the value from the enum you would need to create a new binding and pass that along. But I don´t know exactly why one would do it that way.

e.g.:

```
case .carDetails(let car):
    let binding = Binding<Car> {
        car
    } set: { value, transaction in
        // uncertain what car you want to manipulate here
    }

    ItemView(item: binding)
```

Comment: ok, so, I now see what you did. I am trying to reference the `car` that is passed in the case `let car`... I see you went straight to the car in the view `@State var myCar = Car()` .... is there a way to use the car I pass in the enum associated type instead?

Comment: Yes you could but you would need to create a new binding for that.

Comment: @zumzum The error you mentioned in your edit comes from the compiler being confused what `car` variable to use, since there are two defined. One in the scope of the switch statement and one in the scope of the view.

Comment: yes. You are right. I tried to give different names and it fixes the problem in a way, although, I wanted to use the value coming in from the associated type instead. I now have simply followed this but the `ItemView` is still not quite there yet.

Comment: I don´t think this is a good approach. You are creating multiple sources of truth that would need to be synchronized. In your example it seems you don´t need this associated value at all.

Comment: that's ok. I can do away with the associate value in my real user case. I posted the code following this approach. Still having some issues in the details view not sure can't display things properly.